# Deleting records inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that I am passing through a $_POST variable.  In the foreach loop, I would like to check to see if "delete" has been checked.  If so, I will delete the record.  If delete is not checked, I will update the record.  When I run this the update works perfect.  If I have delete checked - it will delete the first record in the array - not the record with the corresponding id of the record with the checked box.  If I have 2 checked - it will take the first 2.  If I have them all checked - it will obviously then delete all the records.  I have been wrestling with this one all day - looking for a little help.  Thanks.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $slo_id = $_POST['slo_id'];

    foreach ($_POST['score_id'] as $key=>$score_id) {
    $del = $_POST['del'][$key];

    if ($del == 'checked') {

                $sql2 = " DELETE FROM slo_score WHERE score_id = $score_id "; 
            #execute SQL statement 
           $result = mysql_query($sql2); 
        # check for error 
           if (mysql_error()) { print "Database ERROR in SQL Update Statement: " . mysql_error(); }
            }
    else {
        $growth_target = $_POST['growth_target'][$key];
        $final_score = $_POST['final_score'][$key];
        $meets = $_POST['meets'][$key];





                  //update table
      $sql1 = "UPDATE slo_score SET growth_target='$growth_target',final_score='$final_score',meets='$meets' WHERE score_id = $score_id";

         #execute SQL statement 
      $result = mysql_query($sql1); 
    # check for error 
      if (mysql_error()) { print "Database ERROR in SQL Update Statement: " . mysql_error(); } 

        }

        }



        header("location:...);

}
```

Comment: You have to show us your query otherwise we cannot help you very good! Because if you say that it deletes a record means that the conndition is true but your query isn't right

Comment: Wait, I'll imagine your query and fix it! Done!

Comment: Give mysql queries as they will be the most important for the purpose of this question!

Comment: I didn't want to give queries b/c I will get hammered for using mysql rather than mysqli :)  I will edit and put them on there.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $slo_id = $_POST['slo_id'];

    foreach ($_POST['score_id'] as $key=>$score_id) {


    if (isset($_POST['del'][$key])) {

                //use mysqli to delete the record
            }
    else {
        $growth_target = $_POST['growth_target'][$key];
        $final_score = $_POST['final_score'][$key];
        $meets = $_POST['meets'][$key];





                   //update table
          use mysqli to update the record 

        }

        }



        header("location:...);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid looping deletes to MySQL at all costs.

If you are receiving an array of IDs to delete, why not just send that in one (or a few, if this is thousands of IDs we're talking about; chunk them) query:

```
$score_ids = isset($_POST['score_id']) ? $_POST['score_id'] : array();

$score_ids_in = implode("', '", $score_ids);

$sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM slo_score WHERE score_id IN ('%s')", $score_ids_in);

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Of course, this won't give you line by line feedback but it will keep your database from being choked to death.

Also, you already know you should use Mysqli to keep people from destroying your database, extracting sensitive data from it, or both. It's not a huge change from what you're doing now, except it's a lot more secure.